# Registering what txt files are opened

Tags: android, file, action

I guess there is some action, which works when every file is opened. In my case - *.txt file. And I need to get the name of this file.

I found something:

```
Intent.ACTION_VIEW
Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
```

But how to use them? 
My guess-work:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
```

put to my receiver

and a part of code of my **service**:

```
File aFile = new File(filePath);
FileWriter fOut = new FileWriter(aFile, true);
if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.contains(".txt")) fOut.append("DOC " + time1 + " " + date1 + "\n");
```

Please, give me a hint, how to beat this. Thanks a lot.